# Copy web pages from browser including collapsed content? Or expand all collapsed content in a web page?

Tags: firefox, browser, copy-paste, microsoft-word-2007, cross-browser

Does anyone know a trick, app or script that can copy an entire web page, including the collapsed parts, without manually clicking each expand link?

I regularly have to copy (=download) my messages from a site (ATM Firefox into MS Word 2007, but would use any browser that could do this! - probably has to be word as need to include images in the paste).

The problem is, the source page auto-collapses every other thread when one of the 50+ threads thread is expanded.  (There is no "expand all" button on the page like there is in some help pages etc...)

Each thread has its own # mark (which I think is normal)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is copying only the displayed text an option, i.e. scraping the page source and parsing it is not an option? That might work if you didn't need the pictures, only the text. Another possibility is simply mirroring the source code and removing the code that collapses parts of it, which may or may not be difficult

Comment: @InterLinked sorry don't understand your comment ... doesn't look like it assists with achieving what I have asked in my question...

Comment: @InterLinked could you possibly explain how to "mirroring the source code and removing the code that collapses parts of it,"?  So I can try that

Comment: I don't have a go to solution ready for that. What it would entail is copying the HTML for the page and then removing any CSS, etc. that collapses the code, then rendering the page locally.